# Jquery event - how to select entire DIV excluding some inner area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Think of the following HTML code to apply Jquery:

**HTML code:**

```
<div id="outer_div">
  <div id="inner_div_1"></div>
  <div id="inner_div_2"></div>
  <div id="inner_div_3"></div>
</div>
```

By default, the "outer_div" is hidden. It appears while clicked on a button using Jquery show() function.
I wanted to do the following: On click within anywhere of "outer_div" excluding the area within "inner_div_1" , the "outer_div" would again be hidden. I failed while tried the following codes. What should I amend?

**Attempted Jquery 1:**

```
$("#outer_div:not(#inner_div_1)").on("click",function(){
    $("#outer_div").hide("slow");
});
```

**Attempted Jquery 2:**

```
$("#outer_div").not("#inner_div_1").on("click",function(){
    $("#outer_div").hide("slow");
});
```

Your support would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider that a click in the inner div is also a click on the outter div. That being said, you just need to check the target and target parents :

```
$("#outer_div").on("click",function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).closest('#inner_div_1').length) $("#outer_div").hide("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use some of the data in the event

```
$("#outer_div").on("click",function(e){
    if( // Fast check to see if this is the div
        e.target.id !=='inner_div_1'
        // We limit the 'closest()' code to the outer div. This adds children to the exclude
        && $(this).closest('#inner_div_1, #outer_div')[0].id=='outer_div'){
        alert('good click');
    }
});
```

This is a solution for your code now, this works perfect when not too many excluding objects. But no wildcard selectors, which is nice.
And a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zMGyW/).

---

Other properties can be used to, like a class:

```
$("#outer_div").on("click",function(e){
    if( e.target.className!=='even' 
        && $(this).closest('.even, #outer_div')[0].id=='outer_div'){
        alert('yay, clicked an odd');
    }
});
```

[I made 7 lines, gave the even ones a class 'even'](http://jsfiddle.net/zMGyW/1/).

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me :) Tested in in IE (a new one) and FF29. They both do.

Comment: @Martijn If the div has children, it will not work : http://jsfiddle.net/zMGyW/2/

Comment: @Martijn it may work for the OP's testing code, in the actual code, the `#inner_div_1` may contain some other HTML elements (not just text), such as span, button, ... So clicking on these elements (which are still inside the `#inner_div_1` will hide the container (because the `e.target.className` won't match, `e.target` is not the  `#inner_div_1` but some child element inside.

Comment: added a check to see if the `outer_div` is the is the closest element, excluding some targets. Not tested, but should give a way to think. Maybe I can add a demo later